# Invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8" when Upgrading from PG8 to PG9

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, utf-8

Our DB is going to upgrade from postgresql 8.4 to 9.3 and we are asked to do some verification on our legacy app (Rails 2.3.2 app). (Don't laugh, it's a real app that runs for years).
And I use latest pg gem (0.17.1), but it's really big change to move to latest 2.3.18 for rails so I just stay with old rails version.

And one table is storing some binary data (column type is bytea).

Here comes the issue:
When I run 8.4 as backend db, that table can get record inserted.
when I run 9.3 as backend db, the rails app freak out for "invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8" ...

And out db in pg8/9 are all build in UTF8 encoding. And the app code is same.

What I can observe is the SQL generated (logged in test.log) is different:
for 8.4:

```
INSERT INTO "large_keys" ("u_id", "key_value", "key_hash", "created_at", "type", 
"iv")     VALUES(793287954, E'\\3540\\272\\204\\327H\\204w\\021\\341\\362I\\205\\3456\\252', 
NULL, '2014-02-20 10:32:00.869783', E'aes', E'aaabbbcccddd1234’);
```

but 9.3:

```
INSERT INTO "large_keys" ("type", "iv", "key_value", "created_at", "u_id", "key_hash") 
VALUES(E'aes', E'aaabbbcccddd1234', E'\3540\272\204\327H\204w\021\341\362I\205\3456\252', 
'2014-02-20 10:33:46.659190', 793287954, NULL);
```

The main different is key_value is escaped correctly when talking 8.4. but I don't understand which reason make front-end activerecord to behave different?

Thanks in advance for any idea.

Comment: Oh, just realize stackoverflow eat backslash for the first SQL I pasted. in 8.4, it should be:
...
VALUES(793287954, E'\\3540\\272\\204\\327H\\204w\\021\\341\\362I\\205\\3456\\252', NULL, '2014-02-20 10:32:00.869783', E'aes', E'aaabbbcccddd1234’);

Comment: do these inserts work from postgres directly?

Comment: no, it's from rails app.
And I also ran the 2nd SQL in psql directly and get the same error.

Comment: Sorry @Kyrre I am bit slow today.  Is you question that "8.4 produces double slashes but 9.3 doesn't" ?

Comment: yes, that's what I am noticing from log file.

Comment: that issue is gone when I upgrade rails to 2.3.3
But I am still looking for the root cause.

Comment: Correct: Not 2.3.3, but 2.3.6 rails fix that issue.
And the code change is made in 
`
<Rails2.3.6 source root>/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb
`
But changes are scatterd in many places so I don't do further investigation on which point fix this issue.
I think this issue can be closed.